# Connect to Tally ODBC from Python from other network

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, tally

I am not able to connect to tally odbc from another network. I have whitelisted my IP and Opened port 9000. Tally is installed on a machine in cloud. Here is what I am doing:

```
import pyodbc    
conn = pyodbc.connect('Dsn=TallyODBC64_9000;Driver={Tally ODBC Driver};server=20.xx.xx.xx;port=9000')
```

It is giving me this error:

```
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have looked on the internet but couldn't find anything on connecting outside of your network.
Questions:

1. Do I need to install Tally ODBC Driver on my machine?
2. Can you guide me on where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Accessing your server in browser http://20.xx.xx.xx:9000

if it shows `<RESPONSE>TallyPrime Server is Running</RESPONSE>`

then try connecting using ODBC

if its shows nothing, then you need to check whether Port configured in Tally is allowed in Cloud security setting and system firewall settings